# Compare proportions with unknown sample size in one group

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, proportion

I would like to compare the proportion of an outcome (overweight yes/no) in my dataset for different age groups with normative population data that I found publicly available online. I have overweight prevalence for age groups 20-30y, 30-40y, 40-50y and 50-55y for men and women for my data and the control data.
The challenge is that for the control data I only have an estimation of the total sample size (it's based on four yearly questionnaires that were completed by 9000-9500 each year, so in total about 37000 subjects, that's all they published, so it's unknown how large the separate age groups are). I do have frequency, standard error and confidence interval for each data point.
Is there a way to perform a chi square test (or another test) to compare two proportions with unknown exact sample size, but known SE/CI in one group?
Thank you for your suggestions,
Best wishes,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the standard error of each proportion, you should be able to infer the respective sample size

$SE = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$

$n = \frac{p(1-p)}{SE^2}$

Comment: Great, thank you very much!